# Linux: Copy DVD ISO to empty hard disk / partition and boot as if it is a DVD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, iso-image, burning

I have a broken DVD drive and no others available right now to burn a DVD iso to so I'd like to use a empty hard disk instead.

I've tried Unetbootin but that only copies a few megabytes of files - the rest of the image data in the ISO is ignored.

I have verified the ISO is valid and working with VirtualBox. It's MD5 hash is also as expected. But I need to boot at the real BIOS not an emulated one.

I've also tried things like:

`sudo cat /disk/image.iso > /dev/sdb1`

and that got "Permission denied" - no idea why.

Comment: what distro? unetbootin only works on casper based distros...also, what OS do you have running now?

Comment: No guarantees, but you might try using dd instead of cat. Note that it has a special syntax.

Comment: @Journeyman_Geek The OS in question may or may not have been mystery OS 'X' ;)
I'm not sure it's true unetbootin only works on casper based dsitros though

Comment: @zpletan thanks for the DD reminder, it worked enough, in the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end I used dd and a USB stick as a boot disk because somehow booting didn't seem to work for the dvd on the hard disk.

```
sudo dd if=/storeM/os-dvd.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=8M

sudo dd if=/storeM/bootdisk.img of=/dev/sdc
```

Comment: Has it been working perfectly? Have you found any problems with this approach?

Comment: @Pacerier there are probably problems with this approach but in some scenarios it might be ok. I did it a while ago unfortunately so can't give details. Not hard to test with a small bootable ISO though - maybe Puppy.

Comment: Please, let the OS decide how to transfer files efficiently, so use: `cat /storeM/os-dvd.iso > /dev/sdb`. Even with the best settings, `cat` is still going to be faster than `dd` ([see this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538/140353)). Only use `dd` if you need more complicated stuff, such as copying only a specific range of bytes.

Answer (score 7):

For information, since this hits a lot of people using sudo while writing to a file. Here's what happens if you use the cat command:

`sudo cat /disk/image.iso > /dev/sdb1`

is interpreted by the shell as executing `sudo cat /disk/image.iso` and then sending output to `/dev/sdb1`. Only the cat command is privileged; the output redirection isn't.

`dd` avoids these problems since source and target are arguments and part of the privileged command.

Comment: Indeed, because redirection is part of the shell. So either you just type `su`, and then execute the command. Or you use `sudo cat /disk/image.iso | sudo tee /dev/sdb >/dev/null`. I would really suggest to use `cat`, because `dd` can be much slower. Note: when writing an ISO file, **usually** you want to write to a disk (`/dev/sdb`) and not a partition (`/dev/sdb1`).

Answer (score 7):

There is a [difference between an ISO image](https://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin) (for cd) and a hard disk image (applicable to usb also). It is however possible to adjust the iso image, so that it fulfil the requirements of a hard disk image. Such an iso image is called hybrid iso. Linux has a tool that does this adjustment: `isohybrid`.

So here's what I did with success:

```
cp orig_image.iso hybrid.iso
isohybrid hybrid.iso
dd if=hybrid.iso of=/dev/sdd_ bs=8M
```

On Debian 8 the utility is contained in package `syslinux-utils`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MEMDISK](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK) to boot an optical image from a hard drive.

Comment: And of course the site is currently down...

Comment: Btw have you tested this to work successfully? I've had very low success rate of getting "boot from file on hard drive" to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider downloading the file again, also check the integrity, there is a reason you're facing errors. I've never had a problem with UNetBootin.

You can also try [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) if you have a Windows system spare. [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) also has an option to insert an ISO to be bootable from the Windows Bootloader, the iso can be executed from memory or the hard disk but is experimental.

Comment: There is no integrity problem, I validated it's MD5 is as expected.
Universal USB Installer didn't work. I will try EasyBCD.