# why iso image booting from DVD but not from usb?

Tags: usb, iso-image, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between the usb booting mechanism and optical disk booting mechanism?](https://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin)

I have an iso file. I burned it to a DVD now I can boot using that DVD but when I burned that iso image to a usb it not booting at all from the usb.

Why same image is bootable from DVD and not from USB, what I need to do to make it bootable-usb of the same iso image?

Comment: Have you enabled booting from USB in your bios?
How did you "burn" the image to a usb?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to boot. If you're trying to boot something that's Linux, [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is great. For Windows 7, give the official [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) a whirl.

As the question sawdust linked explains, you will need some kind of boot loader for images 'burned' to a USB drive. Both these utilities will take care of that. (Anyone know of a solution for pre-Vista installs?)

Comment: I think UNetBootin works for anything, not just linux. It includes an automatic download feature for some linux distros, which probably confuses people as the GUI is a bit vague.