# How to convert iso file to USB (don't even know how to mount)

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I'm a total total noob who is trying to download Linux Mint on a Mac OS X using a (8 GB) USB flash drive. I know there is some way to go into terminal and convert the iso file, but I don't know how.

-see updated question at bottom-

Here's the things I have tried so far:

1. `sudo dd bs=4M if=[linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso] of=/dev/disk2s1`
   (result: `dd: bs: illegal numeric value`)
2. `~/path/to/Users/[my name]/linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.img ~/path/to/Users/[my name]/linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso`
   `-bash: /Users/[my name]/path/to/Users/[my name]/linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.img (result: No such file or directory)`

Maybe for #1 the "/dev/disk2s1" part is wrong? How do I find the number for the USB that goes after "/dev/sd"? (I can only find "/dev/disk2s1").

EDIT: I followed mypal125's advice and plugged into Terminal:

```
sudo dd bs=4000000 if=linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso of=/dev/disk2
```

Here's my new problem: I get the message :"The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." I have an option to initialize? Is there something I am able to do with this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: *"How to convert iso file to USB"* -- Former is a file specification.  Latter is a bus specification.  Apples to oranges; you're asking for an imposiible conversion.  *"USB drive"*  -- Ambiguous device.  Perhaps you mean a USB ***flash*** drive?

Comment: Your question seems to (improperly) assume that the ISO image file that you have is a *hybrid ISO* image that is also suitable for a device that requires an MBR.  See http://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin

Comment: Also: `~` is short for the path to your home directory, which might be something like `/home/[my name]` or `/Users/[my name]` — so specifying them both is like specifying `/Users/[my name]/Users/[my name]` — *just like the error message says*.  That probably doesn't exist, so don't do that.

Comment: @G-Man, this is OSX here so its /Volumes/$USER/...... but still valid point

Comment: @user443598 -- Regarding your edit: since you're having a problem with an answer, be sure to add a comment to that answer so that the author is aware of the issue that you're having and the revised question.  BTW the verb for terminal input is "type" and not *"plug"*.

Comment: @linuxdev2013: Yeah, I'm not familiar with OS X, but the fact that there was an error message saying `/Users/[my name]/path/to/Users/[my name]/…: No such file or directory` was crying out for attention.

Comment: Valid point I misread that as 2 separate errors nice catch

Answer (score 3):

Let's dissect the error.

```
dd: bs: illegal numeric value
```

`bs`: you set `bs=4M` in your command line.
`illegal numeric value`: This means the value of `bs` isn't valid ("legal")

If I recall correctly, the "m" in `bs` has to be lowercase. Of course you can use `bs=4000000` (4 million, 4M) instead to avoid this.

Also, the guide (I assume) you are using is assuming Linux, and Linux uses `/dev/sdx` for hard drives, flash drives, etc. Darwin (the base for Mac OS X) uses `/dev/diskx`. Also, `/dev/disk2s1` is pointing to the first partition of disk 3. (the computer is counting from zero) You probably mean `/dev/disk2`, which points to disk 3, plain and simple. The reason behind this is because the .iso file contains its own "partition table," or what stores where partitions are. `/dev/disk2` will let you overwrite the partition table.

**TL;DR:** `sudo dd bs=4000000 if=linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso of=/dev/disk2` on Mac OS X assuming flash drive is on `/dev/disk2`, `<sudo> dd bs=4000000 if=linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso of=/dev/sdb` on Linux assuming flash drive is on `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: I would use this - is a lot easier. ==> http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This answer improperly assumes that the ISO image file is a *hybrid ISO* image that is also suitable for a device that requires an MBR.  See http://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin

Comment: @sawdust not improper assumption Linux Mint (a Ubuntu family OS ) IS hybrid as are 98% of modern linux OSes these days.

Comment: whs sadly that is not a viable option for mac as it is licensed in such a way it is not approved by apple -- if this is not of concern to user -- aka he/she is ditching MacOSX and not using for schooling or otherwise then sure but there are better options too.

Comment: Yeah I tried to download Unetbootin but it doesn't work for Macs, as mentioned. Is there any equivalent program for Macs?

Comment: if dd is failing you try the mac version of unetbootin found here:  > http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/608/unetbootin-mac-608.zip/download?use_mirror=hivelocity  If that was the version you wer trying what error did you recieve?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the partition part (disk**s1**  part in bold) as you write to the drive NOT a partition (for the context of this question at least -- as there are MORE ADVANCED use cases and ways to safely do to a partition)

As for the 4M size issue how big is the actual USB stick ? is there other stuff on the stick presently ---if so back it up if its meaningful to you and re-run command (with sudo prepended like so (shown below)

> sudo dd bs=4M if=/Volumes/Users/[my name]/linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso of=/disk2

--this assumes it is in the 'root' of your /home directory AND that there are 2 additional drives / non system partitions beyond the internal one, check via finder OR udisks (aka Disk Utility) if this is indeed the case and amend of=/disk# accordingly --if it is in (more likely your Downloads folder run like below:

> sudo dd bs=4M if=/Volumes/Users/[my name]/Downloads/linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso of=/disk2

EDIT:  As a native alternative  use Disk Utility like so:

1) open Disk utility and select that target drive (the usb) in 'destination' field

2) navigate to the linuxmint iso and place it in the 'source' field and hit 'restore disk image' should this fail Please update via the comments what errors are presented