# Possible to format a microSD card in ISO9660 format?

Tags: format, micro-sd-card

As title, is it possible to format a microSD card in ISO9660 format?

More questions, and would I then be able to (or how could I) save to that card from a computer?

More details, Windows or OS X (or other Unix) platforms are available to me

**That's a weird thing to want to do, what are you really up to?!** ... well to keep the question on topic I'll go into more detail if required. If the answer's no it doesn't really matter!

Comment: Format?  You could write an ISO image file to an SDcard, but then it would have limited utility.  Windows wouldn't know what do do with it.  Linux is more flexible with devices and filesystems, but would require proper mounting.  You're probably asking an XY question.  See http://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin

Comment: ah ok, are you saying then that ISO9660 isn't a 'format or file system'?

Comment: ISO 9660 is a filesystem that (is intended to) occupies the entire medium, and is not expected to exist within a partition like other (mass storage) filesystems.  The `mkfs` utilities are designed to format the specified partition (within a device) with the requested  filesystem.  Usually the ISO image is created using `mkisofs`, and then written to the medium.  The tools for ISO 9660 are designed for the intended write-once medium, and not for a read/writable mass-storage device.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful and makes sense - i think i'm on to a loser - briefly: old hardware sampler, uses own proprietary file system but will read iso9660 cd-roms, it can use microSD card with a SCSI to microSD card bridge - i figured if i could 'format the microSD card as iso9660' i might be able to save stuff to it from a computer - for use in the sampler