# I want to write an ISO without a partition table to an USB stick

Tags: usb, iso-image, bootable-media

So, I have an ISO that I want to write to a bootable USB stick. The problem is that the ISO does not have a partition table. From my understanding, this type of ISO should be written on a DVD. Can I write my ISO to my 8GB USB? I also tried it via "dd" and it did not work.

Edit: I tried it in Virtualbox and it worked. It means that the image is bootable.

Edit: Maybe add a partition table to the ISO?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert the plain ISO image into a Hybrid ISO image.  See https://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin

Comment: @sawdust Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ISO is not Linux or BSD. It's a MacOS ISO. Still Unix-like, but it gives me this error: `bob@I-am-Bob:~/Downloads$ isohybrid OSX-Mavericks.iso 
isohybrid: OSX-Mavericks.iso: boot loader does not have an isolinux.bin hybrid signature. Note that isolinux-debug.bin does not support hybrid booting`

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

In FreeBSD:

`dd if=./your-DVD.iso of=/dev/da0 bs=1m conv=sync` where `da0` is the USB stick

In Linux:

`dd if=./your-DVD.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1m` where `X` is your USB stick.

NOTE the easiest way to discover which device name corresponds to your USB stick would be to perform an `ls /dev` before, and after inserting your USB stick.

Comment: I will try it now, thank you

Comment: Got an error: dd: invalid number: ‘1m’. Here is a screenshot https://ibb.co/jys8pxv

Comment: Btw, to discover the name of the usb, cannot I use "sudo fdisk -l"?

Comment: Possibly. I only suggested using `ls /dev` before, and after. Because it was the simplest solution to discovering your USB device I could think of. :)

Comment: And about my error?

Comment: Oh I got it. It should be "1M" not "1m". And you should run it with sudo.

Comment: `CDFS` *is* a file system of it's own. You need not be concerned about "slices', or "partitions". It creates an Index table for any of the `CD` standards (file systems) it was created with. Given your success vs. failed attempts. I would suspect that your VBOX was written *correctly* whereas your other attempt was not. :)

Comment: Definitely with `sudo`! :)

Comment: Thank you for your attention!

Comment: My pleasure! :)