# Booting Intel NUC from a SD card

Tags: linux, boot, usb, sd-card

I have [Intel NUC Kit NUC8i7BEH](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126140/intel-nuc-kit-nuc8i7beh.html) and I am trying to boot a Linux from an SD card on it (tried both OpenWrt and Ubuntu without success). It simply does not detect it as a valid bootable device.

I have found this [article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024603/mini-pcs/intel-nuc-kits.html) saying that this is not supported, but that it works if I make SD card "USB-like". The links referenced in the article are not useful. I am on Linux and tried different way to make such a SD card which would work as USB.

Mostly I tried to use unetbootin in different ways but resulting device was still not bootable.

What exactly would "USB-like" mean? What standard does this relate to? What should be the file system, partition structure, what should be in MBR?

Any other way to make a test SD card with whatever on it just to get over BIOS not finding the device to boot from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly would "USB-like" mean?

That IMO is a misleading choice of words.
There are no alternate formats that makes a SD card more or less bootable.
Those articles also conflate a (bootable) device and (bootable) media.

The built-in SD card connector (of the NUC) is probably attached to a MMC/SD_card controller.
This MMC/SD_card controller (with installed medium) is a device, but apparently not a bootable device in this NUC.
(Technically there is a difference between MMC and SD cards, i.e. the specifications are published by different organizations.)

An SD card is simply a medium (i.e. singular of media) for data storage.  It does have internal electronics, but that is only to provide a PC-compatible sector-based interface instead of its native NAND flash interface of erase-blocks and pages.
By itself the SD card is not a device.  It must be inserted into a connector/socket/slot, and accessed by the CPU with suitable interface electronics, e.g. an SD_card controller or a USB card reader/adapter.

*"USB-like"* would mean to not use this built-in MMC/SD_card controller of the NUC , but use your SD card in a USB-to-SD_card adapter (aka [USB card reader](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=sd+card+reader&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A1292110011%2Cn%3A3151491&crid=1P2JCP78QDCGX&linkId=7645ad360bf08b1a2192f8f3beeffd23&tag=groovypostcom-20&ref=as_li_ss_tl)) (which will emulate a HDD) plugged into a USB port.

> What standard does this relate to?

You will be using your SD card (in its USB card reader) just as if it was a USB flash drive.
USB flash drives emulate a removable hard disk drive.
HDDs for PCs adhere to the ATA (aka ATAPI) specification.

> What should be the file system, partition structure, what should be in MBR?

You would need to use a [hybrid ISO image](https://superuser.com/questions/410305/what-is-the-difference-between-the-usb-booting-mechanism-and-optical-disk-bootin/410493#410493) that is writable to either a DVD or USB flash drive.  You will be using your SD card (in its USB card reader) just as if it was a USB flash drive.

Comment: Ohhh. So because they have a real SD card controller and not internally USB adapter, this does not work? Hm.