# Copy ISO to HDD and boot from it

Tags: boot, ssd

I have no usb sticks left but my PC has three SDD drives empty.  So what I am trying to achieve is to copy Pop OS iso to one of the drives, and then boot from that drive to install the persistent OS on the first and bigger drive.

The thing is that although I can copy with no issues using Disks as explained here: [Linux: Copy DVD ISO to empty hard disk / partition and boot as if it is a DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/334187/linux-copy-dvd-iso-to-empty-hard-disk-partition-and-boot-as-if-it-is-a-dvd)

When I reboot my PC and press F12 to select the boot source the SDD does not show up on the list, only an SD Card that I am using to get the LIVE CD environment running.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW: No, I cant write the image to the SD Card and install from there, for some reason I can boot the installer and start the process but while is copying installation files it fails with IO error, so I really need to boot from the SDD.

Comment: you should save iso as file and add menu entry in grub

Comment: It is unclear which of the methods in the mentioned post you've used to write the image to your hdd

Comment: @mashuptwice I first tried DD. It did not work. Then I tried using balena etcher. That did not work either. I also used Disks tool. Did not work.

Comment: @alecxs Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot https://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso https://www.xmodulo.com/boot-iso-image-from-grub.html

Comment: @mashuptwice I read through that document, but it says "that GRUB MUST be installed on the system". How come? My drives are empty. I do not have a any grub config file to edit and add an entry because I have three SDD completely blank

Comment: @MatiasBarrios If I understand you correctly you don't have any OS installed on the machine on any drive and all of the drives in the computer are completely blank? May I ask you how you've written the images on the drives without any OS installed?

Comment: if you copy the content of iso to fat32 partition it should work

Comment: @mashuptwice I loaded a LIVE environment from an SD Card.

Comment: @alecxs Ill try

Comment: @MatiasBarrios You've said that the SD card throws IO errors. There might be a physical problem with the SD which could lead to inconsistency of transferred data. At this point you might want to use a different boot device, like a USB stick. If you don't have a USB stick on hand you could use something like [drivedroid](https://www.drivedroid.io/)

Comment: @mashuptwice but using a different boot device is exactly what I am looking for. Thats why I am trying to copy the iso to an empty harddrive and boot from there. So I can clean install in another drive

Comment: @MatiasBarrios It is highly unlikely that you can bootstrap a working system from a broken one (IO errors). Again: the simplest thing would be to use a different live boot media, (USB, different SD, drivedroid, USB harddrive, network boot, DVD) as it seems your current one is throwing IO errors and therefore very likely damaged. Please edit your question to make clear that you are actually using a live OS on a broken SD card to  try toaccomplish your goal.